# Findstr ERRORLEVEL returns wrong level if I type dot's of the same length as the search string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line, findstr

I create batch `(.bat)` script where I use `findstr` with the `if / else` statement.

#### The part that works well:

- If I type a valid string that matches a line in the file to be searched, it takes me to the `IF` **<- this is OK**
- If i type not valid string, it takes me to the `ELSE`**<- this is OK**

#### The part that doesn't work well:

- If I type **dot's** instead of letters (**of the same length**), it takes me to the `IF`. For example, if I enter `....`, the number of characters matches the string `blue`
- Why? The dots don't match any string in my file, so I should go to `ELSE`. What is wrong with my code?

---

#### My `searchable_file.xml`:

```
dev
current
old
stable
oldest
newest
blue
green
```

#### My `findstr` script:

```
SET /P SELECTION=

FINDSTR /R /C:"^%SELECTION%$" searchable_file.xml > NUL

IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO [OK] The value entered is valid.
) ELSE (
    ECHO [ERROR] The path entered does not exist. Try again.
)
```

Comment: Please read the output of the command `FINDSTR /?`.

Comment: You may, as a result decide to use its `/C:` or `/L` literal options instead of its default `/R`egular expression option, which sees `.` characters as a wildcard, 'any', character.

Comment: Oh, it's obvious. I don't know why I didn't notice it before. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/R` in `FINDSTR /R /C:"^%SELECTION%$"  file.txt` means using **R**EGEX (where a dot serves as a wildcard). Just removing `/R` is useless, as it is the standard anyway. Replace it with `/L` (**L**iteral) instead.

Of course this means, `^` for "start of line" and `$` for "end of line" won't work anymore (they are REGEX), but you can add the `/B` (**B**egin of line) and `/E` (**E**nd of line) switches instead:

```
FINDSTR /L /B /E /C:"%SELECTION%" file.txt
```

or use the `/X` switch (whole line):

```
FINDSTR /L /X /C:"%SELECTION%" file.txt
```

undocumented but supported feature of `findstr`: you can combine switches with a single `/`:

```
FINDSTR /LXC:"%SELECTION%" file.txt
```

Maybe you also want to use the `/i` switch (**I**gnore capitalization) to find `blue`, `Blue`, `BLUE` etc.:

```
FINDSTR /ILXC:"%SELECTION%" file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The `findstr` command treats `.` as a wildcard character, so searching a string for dots will return any word with the same amount of characters as the amount of dots. For example, searching for `t.e` in `the` will return `the`. If you searched for `.*`, it would return almost everything, as `*` allows wildcard characters to match with any number of occurrences. You should be able to escape the wildcard characters using a backslash, for example `\.\.\.` would only search for dots and not other characters.
[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr)